# PayPal integrate in ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, paypal

I am new in ionic. Actually, I want to implement PayPal in ionic 1. I don't understand this

```
.constant('shopSettings',{
payPalSandboxId :'ATNKZfuLJFZ2pjYuWpCUVXhN3vNCYRhtD5G9IBnTLBu7cdZjFYf48_6eVjTGEwrd9fQuEKe5x5dWfEWi',
payPalProductionId : 'production id here',
payPalEnv: 'Sandbox', // for testing production for production
payPalShopName : 'MyShopName',
payPalMerchantPrivacyPolicyURL : 'url to policy',
payPalMerchantUserAgreementURL : ' url to user agreement '
 })
```

Plese help me how to get this value.
show me the error "there was a problem setting up this payment. please visit the paypal website to check your account"

Answer (score 0):

these are paypal API credential you need to get it from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/)